# Вывод Image в DataGridView

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

Возник такой вопрос, уже который день не могу решить проблему. Не получается в DGV вывести Image, путь к которому хранится в БД, а сам файл лежит в каталоге.

```
var documents = _repository.Of<Document>()
                .Search(x => x.CaseId == @case.Id)
                .ToArray();

        foreach(var document in documents)
        {
            DocumentGrid.Rows.Add(document.Id, document.PathToImage);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение.

```
using System.Drawing;



...
 foreach(var document in documents)
        {

            DocumentGrid.Rows.Add(document.Id, Bitmap.FromFile(document.PathToImage));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

На сайте документации Microsoft есть такая статья: [Вывод изображений в ячейках элемента управления DataGridView в Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-display-images-in-cells-of-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

Comment: Зачем мне Column, если я вместе с коллекцией вывожу image в row?

Comment: Вы просто передаете путь до картинки, а не саму картинку. Сделайте из нее Bitmap - и вуаля